# iOS/Objective-C: UINavigationBar delegate not called

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

Here are 3 controllers - ViewController subclass of viewController, SecViewController subclass of viewController, nvgc subclass of UINavigationController.

SecViewController is child controller of nvgc and pushes to viewController. In SecViewController, I use delegate method of UINavigationBar but it never gets called. I tried to use it in nvgc, but it didn't work either. Kindly help me locate the issue.

```
#import "nvgc.h"
@interface nvgc ()<UINavigationBarDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation nvgc

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationBar.delegate=self;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.delegate=self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPushItem:(UINavigationItem *)item{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item{
    return NO;
}
-(void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item{
}
-(void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPushItem:(UINavigationItem *)item{
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked my friend.Then I knew from him that my scene structure is bad.I only use push method but not pop.Finally,I modify my scene structure.And I change to use code to push controller but not storyboard.Then UINavigationBar delegate is called.